# Maritime routing using postgres and postgis

Tags: postgresql

I've created a vector grid of 1km x 1km distance(grid being a graph of edges each 1km) but the table itself has billions of rows, would it be wise to run pgr_dijkstra on such a huge data just for the sake of accuracy but trading off query speed?

Comment: it would certainly be wise if you need that accuracy...,) by the way you ask I reckon this depends largely on your application and it's requirements, making this hard to give a non-opinion-based answer to. specify a little, give a hint about what you need it for and maybe explain, even if just to me, what the grid is about...

Comment: basically I want to be able to calculate distances between two given ports, so i started off with created of 1km by 1km grid in QGIS,which i found the centroids of and later connecting each of these centroids to created edges or my routing graph,do you think this is the right approach?

Comment: are those open sea ports? If I get this right, and you want to calculate the shortes path along those edges you derived from a regular grid over the oceans, you would simply detour the direct, straight (or spherical) connection along those gridded nodes, no? why don't you simply get the geographical distance between two given ports? or, aren't there preferred or mandatory routes/courses for ships to travel between ports or continents or around currents, and can you maybe find the data for those? in that case pg_routing might be an option